# Duplex communication using Java websocket

Tags: java, websocket

I am using Tyrus 1.7 API for Java websocket development.

I have developed a server and client.

I want to send information to client without client's request.
Whenever client is connected, I want to send information.

Can we do that using Tyrus API or different java API will do that.

Kindly waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use @OnOpen.

We can send information to client after initial connection using @OnOpen.
Example is below:

```
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session) {
    logger.info("Client with session id:"+session.getId()+" connected.");

    //use either session.getAsyncRemote() or session.getBasicRemote()


}
```